# How to pass a undefined number of optional parameters/arguments to a python 3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to pass 3 obligatory parameters when executing a python script but the program also can receive a undefined number of paramters always greater than 3 for example

```
my_prgoram.py 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and also

```
my_prgoram.py 1 2 3 4
```

I'm trying to do this with the `argparse` module so far I have this

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="how to run the script: [my_prgoram.py 3 4 5 7 [n]... ] 
    )

# Add the positional parameter
parser.add_argument('first', help="number of cards")
parser.add_argument('cvaluen1', type=int, help="the first value")
parser.add_argument('cvaluen2', type=int, help="the second value")

# Parse the arguments
arguments = parser.parse_args()

# Finally print the passed string
print(arguments.first)
print(arguments.cvaluen1)
print(arguments.cvaluen2)
```

Answer (score 0):

ArgumentParser.parse_known_args() might be of help:

```
>>> parser.parse_known_args('1 2 3 4 5 6'.split(' '))
(Namespace(cvaluen1=2, cvaluen2=3, first='1'), ['4', '5', '6'])
```